# How do I create a many-to-many relationship to the same object?

Tags: lookup, master-detail, junction-object

I have a need to create a hierarchy of products, where one product is the 'base' product and other products are used to make up a final item. For example the 'base' product is a chair, but the customer can select different armrests (each a product), backrest, etc. An armrest can fit on more than one base chair. So it's a many to many relationship.

On a standard junction object there are 2 master-detail fields. With the relationship between them being to the same object, I can't use master-detail, as it expects a different object. So my question is, is it ok to use lookups instead of the master-detail fields, or is there another solution that would be better?

Comment: Irene -- does the child Product have a separate price, or a price at all, depending on which parent product it is associated with on some quote?  I ask because if you are going to use pricebooks and pricebookentries, the design gets more complex. For example on Chair `Foo`, the Armrest `A` costs $50 but on Chair 'Bar`, the same Armrest `A` costs $55.

Comment: No, the price isn't of any interest. This is needed to create a form for the rep to select which product and which parts related to that product to compile a quote from.

Comment: Lookup is perfectly fine. It suits the same purpose.